# Using both Glide, Retrofit and OkHttp 4.x in the same app, compilation error due to versioning issue

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp, android-glide

My application uses both `Glide` with OkHttp backend, `Retrofit` with OkHttp backend and `OkHttp` directly. My dependency section in my `build.gradle` file therefore looks like this:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.10.0'

implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'

implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.14.2'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:4.14.2'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.14.2'
```

I use the `annotationProcessor` declaration because I need to have a custom AppGlideModule class (I use a custom DNS):

```
@GlideModule
public class CustomGlideModule extends AppGlideModule {
  @Override
  public void registerComponents(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Glide glide, @NonNull Registry registry) {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().dns(new MyDns()).build();

    OkHttpUrlLoader.Factory factory = new OkHttpUrlLoader.Factory(client);

    registry.replace(GlideUrl.class, InputStream.class, factory);
  }
}
```

The above class **won't compile** (with Android Studio highlighting an error in red) if I use a more recent version (say, 4.10.0 instead of 3.10.0) of `OkHttp` in my build.gradle file:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.10.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:4.10.0'
```

What happens is that `client` is not recognized to be of type `Call.Factory`, surprisingly. If you look up the types, they do seem to match. I can't explain this behavior and this is my first question.

My second question is, considered that

- Glide 4.14.2 has been linked against OkHttp 3.10.0
- Retrofit 2.9.0 has been linked against OkHttp 3.14.9

which `OkHttp` version shall I declare in my `build.gradle` file? I also use `OkHttp` directly, so it makes sense to explictly declare the dependency in `build.gradle`.

Comment: Please let me know where we need to call `CustomGlideModule` in our app ?